Need help with Chandelier wiring/install
https://imgur.com/a/shn0g8D
I am trying to replace our existing chandelier with a new one we bought. This is the first time I have attempted anything like this and the instructions are essentially nonexistent. I made sure the power is off to the light and tested to make sure the wires weren’t live so I am seemingly ready to install it I think, but I’m unsure about several things.
First, our breaker box already has a ground wire from when the previous owner installed the old light fixture, but so does the bracket for the new chandelier. Most things I saw online mention to connect them if it’s in the actual chandelier wiring, but it’s not. Do we need to braid both wires or is it fine to remove the one on the bracket?
Second, does the bracket just get screwed in to the junction box? I only ask as the screws seem too large and I could only screw them in as far as shown in the picture, which is nothing. Again, the instructions are nonexistent for how to install it, and I’m not the most handy person so I thought it best to confirm.
Sorry if these are very basic questions! Very new to the whole DIY home-improvement stuff. We will have to worry about shrinking the opening a bit since it’s bigger than the new mount, but that’s for another post!

New bracket partially screwed in

New bracket

Junction box

Can you show us a pic of the chandelier side of things?


Do we need to braid both (ground) wires or is it fine to remove the one on the bracket?

All bare copper and/or green insulated wires in the box, on the bracket, and from the fixture (if present) should be connected together using wire nuts or other robust method. NOTE: your question implies that the new fixture has no ground wire/provisions for grounding. If this is the case then I question the quality of the fixture and recommend that you ensure it is an approved fixture for your locale (i.e., make sure it is UL Listed).

does the bracket just get screwed in to the junction box?

YES, but not with those screws, which are wood or sheet-metal screws. The box has threaded tabs designed to accept 8/32 machine screws so that is the type of screw you should use. Regretfully you have probably damaged the 8/32 threads in the original tapped screw holes, by driving those other screws in. Try some short 8/32 screws, if they don't work because the threads are damaged, get some shorter screws like the ones you forced in and fasten with that.

The box appears to have two pairs of tapped mounting holes. If one pair is damaged then the other pair is likely fine. They look to be different sizes, e.g. 8-32 and 10-32.
